# Equation related to roots of unity

Tags: number-theory, roots-of-unity

I came across an equation in a note but it did not compile in my mind.
Here is the equation:

$$\prod_{k=1}^p(1+\varepsilon^kx)=1+x^p$$

where $\varepsilon=e^{2\pi i/p}$ and $p$ is an odd prime number.

I have tried to prove that every coefficient of $x^k$ equals $0$($1<k<p$) but can someone show me a more elegant proof?

Comment: Something isn't right. Look at the case $p=2$. Then $\varepsilon$ can be either $1$ or $-1$. Both choices yields false result, i.e respectivelly $(1+x)^2 = 1+x^2$ and $1-x^2 = 1+x^2$. Probably $\varepsilon$ shouldn't be equal to $1$ and instead of $+$ signs you should consider $-$ signs everywhere, no?

Comment: Both sides represents polynomials with equal $p$ roots and  with the same leading coefficient. Therefore they are equal. There should be $x^p-1$ and the product of $x-\epsilon^k$ ,$\epsilon \neq 1.$

Comment: @DominikKutek  Maybe $\epsilon^k$ should be interpreted as $k$-th root of $x^p-1=0$ instead of $k$-th power of ANY root of $x^p-1=0$.

Comment: Indeed, whether $\varepsilon^k$ is the $k-$th roof of $x^p=1$, or it's the $k-$th power of any fixed root (different from $1$), then $\prod_{k=1}^p (1-\varepsilon^kx)$ would be the same and equal to $1-x^p$, as Ryszard Szwarc explained.

Comment: Alternatively, $\epsilon = e^{2\pi i/p}$.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, $\varepsilon$ is the $p$th root of unity.

Comment: Chen Xu: There are p pth roots of unity. Which one do you mean by  ?

Comment: Ok, let us stick to $\varepsilon = e^{2\pi i/p}$ notation as @Guangliang suggested p is an odd integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The condition should be $p$ is an odd integer.**

Let $f(x) = \prod_{k=1}^p(1+\epsilon^kx)$ and $g(x) = 1+x^p$.

Let $x_i = -1/\epsilon^i$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, p\}$.

We have $f(x_i) = 0$ for $i\in \{1, \ldots, p\}$.  Other the other hand,
$$g(x_i) = 1+(-1)^p\frac1{\epsilon^{ip}} = 1+(-1)^p.$$

For odd integer $p$, $g(x_i) = 0$.  Since both $f$ and $g$ are $p$-th power polynomials, if they equal on $p+1$ ($f(0) = g(0)$) different points, then they must equal.